# ajax request in asp.net

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services

I have a asp.net project which is using JQuery to send and receive data with server.

In server side i have a web service which is responding the requests.
the problem is with JSON which response is not complete. 

for example when i send a request to a method result is :

```
{"param1":"salam","p2":"alike"
```

which result have to be:

```
{"param1":"salam","p2":"alike"}
```

also i mention that is problem occur when i publish my site to IIS 7.0 in windows server 2008.

Comment: I solved this problem by change the ContentType of my response

Old ContentType was: 
**application/json**
New ContentType was: 
**plain/text**

Comment: also you can solve problem by following this action:

http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/